# Компиляция Pug в HTML

Tags: jade, pug

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью командной строки компилировать PUG файл в HTML и как отслеживать изменения в PUG файле?

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/pugjs/pug

Все же написано.

1. Установить [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/).
2. Запустить командную строку.
3. Выполнить команду `npm install pug`
4. Выполнить команду (для последней версии node.js) `npm install pug-cli -g`
5. Выполняете команду `pug --help`. Дальше увидите список всех доступных команд.

Пример:

Создаете проект **-->** В нем файл **index.pug** **-->** Выполняете команду `pug -w index.pug` **-->** Получаете скомпилированный **index.html** (в этой же директории).

Comment: Спасибо. Пропустила шаг npm install pug-cli -g для последней версии nodejs, поэтому не существовало команды pug. Уже все работает.